# Change order of the Event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a control (button) with a messagebox containing the text "Test A" and added a delegate with another message "Test B". The code below first shows the messge "Test A`" and then "Test B":

```
c.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test B");        
};
```

I need something similar to this code I did that is not working properly:

```
EventHandler handler;
c.click -= handler;
handler = delegate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Test B");
};
c.Click += handler;
```

I need to change the sequence, that is, show the message "Test B", then "Test A". Is it possible?

Comment: By `I have a control (button)` do you mean you have a user control, that consists of `Button` and is being used in some `WPF form` ?

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for your question. I'm not using WPF. There are situations where I need to supplement the existing already putting a delegate but I have to change the execution sequence.

Comment: This is very, very bad idea - to rely on event handlers execution order. Note, that in general, you can't predict, who else will subscribe this event. If the logic of your code depends on execution order, better throw it away and write new one.

Comment: There is a whole new concept of [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) in wpf. In normal `event` execution order of handlers is somewhat undefined.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis for your comment. My application has a compiler that works correctly. The user chooses a control on the screen and write code in C # for this control. Before recording in the database, the user has the option to want if this event occurs before the code already written for the control or if the code you have written will have priority over the system code.

Comment: Perhaps one event who calls events in correct order? `void handler(object sender, EventArgs e) { systemCode(sender, e); userCode(sender, e); }` or reversed as `void handler(object sender, EventArgs e) { userCode(sender, e); systemCode(sender, e); }`?

Comment: @danielvillage: I think, that it is better to handle the event once in *your* code, and call some sort of template method implementation, which will manage the order of code blocks execution, in the handler. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @Dennis, thanks one more time. Ideas and suggestions are always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that your program contains a compiler of some sort, and that the user is able to specify whether their code should run before existing code or after. It seems to me that you can simply handle the users code in an event handler of your own, which runs both your and the users code, in the desired order (as Nikola already mentioned).

In other words, don't expose these events to your users code directly, but 'wrap' them with an event handler of your own. Nothing changes from the users point of view - they still think they've got direct access to the event. But you control how you process your users code, so you're free to insert a layer in-between to guarantee a correct execution order:

```
c.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (hasUserEventHandler && runUserEventHandlerFirst)
        UserEventHandler(sender, e);

    StandardEventHandler(sender, e);

    if (hasUserEventHandler && !runUserEventHandlerFirst)
        UserEventHandler(sender, e);
};
```

I mean, you *could* do something like this:

```
public void SwapDelegateOrder(object obj, string eventName)
{
    // Fetch the underlying event handler field (let's *assume* it has the same name):
    var delegateField = obj.GetType().GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var mcDelegate = delegateField.GetValue(obj) as MulticastDelegate;
    if (mcDelegate == null)
        return;

    // Get the add and remove methods:
    var evt = obj.GetType().GetEvent(eventName);
    var add = evt.GetAddMethod(true);
    var remove = evt.GetRemoveMethod(true);

    // Remove all invocations...
    var invocations = mcDelegate.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (var invocation in invocations)
        remove.Invoke(obj, new object[] { invocation });

    // ...and add them back in, in reverse order (*assuming* that invocations are called in the order they're added):
    foreach (var invocation in invocations.Reverse())
        add.Invoke(obj, new object[] { invocation });
}
```

But that's based on assumptions about compiler and runtime implementation (event field name and execution order). What if some of these details are changed in a compiler update or in the next .NET framework version? You don't have control over that, but you do have control over your own code.

Comment: Well, that just goes to show how unreliable this approach is. It's possible to create custom `add` and `remove` methods for events, so that's yet another factor that can break this code. Apparently Winforms controls store all event handlers in a single `EventHandlerList` rather than using a backing field for each event.

Comment: I made a slight modification to the code and it worked properly. Thank you so much for your help. It is a great connoisseur of the subject. Thanks again Pieter.

Answer (score 3):

You can unregister and register it again:

```
button1.Click -= button1_Click; // unregister main event

            button1.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) // reigster new one
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Test B");
            };

            button1.Click += button1_Click; // register again old
```

Button click Event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Test A");
}
```

Now it will call Call **Test B** first and secondly **Test A**